# JavaScript - For loop button onclick

Tags: javascript, html

I've a javascript that goes through for loop, make table in HTML page and then calls specific function to update specific values for that user.

```
function getUsers() {
  //get all users as "parsedJSON" array
  for (var i=0; i<countrows; i++ ) {
    row.insertCell(0).innerHTML = parsedJSON[i].samaccountname;
    row.insertCell(1).innerHTML = parsedJSON[i].givenname;
    row.insertCell(2).innerHTML = parsedJSON[i].surname;
    var userName = parsedJSON[i].samaccountname;
    row.insertCell(3).innerHTML = "<button id='userName' onclick = 'updateUser(this.id)'> ActionUser</button>";
  }
}

function updateUser(userName) {
    //Function with about 30 lines to update user
}
```

Now, my question is: How can I know, which specific user's button was clicked and how can I pass its username to updateUser function?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Is  `samaccountname` is same as `userName` by which you will update user?

Comment: You provided too few details. At least some markup and the array structure are necessary to elaborate an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here

```
var userName = parsedJSON[i].samaccountname;
row.insertCell(3).innerHTML = "<button id='userName' onclick = 'updateUser(this.id)'> ActionUser</button>";
```

You are actually assigning the string "userName" into the button instead of passing the value of `userName`, so your code should be

```
row.insertCell(3).innerHTML = "<button id='" + userName + "' onclick = 'updateUser(this.id)'> ActionUser</button>";
```

For identifying the clicked button, since you are passing the button's `id` to the `updateUser` function, you can use `document.getElementById` to get the clicked element.

```
function updateUser(userName) {
    var clickedButton = document.getElementById('username');

    // This will work if this function is guaranteed to only be used by HTML element
    var thisButton = this;
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Thum. This is exactly what I needed. Much appreciated. :)